# Why is my Laravel relationship very slow?

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

I have 3 Models in my Laravel project

Customers, SetIndustrialEstate, and CustomerUser.
I build simple relationship like this in my Customers Model:

```php
public function setindustrialestate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SetIndustrialEstate');
}

public function customeruser()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CustomerUser');
}
```

In my Estates Model I have:

```php
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Customer','set_industrial_estate_id');
}
```

I have arround 50.000 entries in customer and customeruser. And also arround 2000 entries of industrial estates. Loading time is realy slow (2 minutes loading) if I try to get Customers of SetIndustrialEstates with CustomerUser. But why?

My ressource of IndustrialEstates is looking like this:

```php
'customers' => $this->customers()->with('customeruser')->get(),
```

And also this is my query to get only pagination of SetIndustrialEstates and load customers including customeruser:

```php
return IndustrialEstateResource::collection(SetIndustrialEstate::orderBy('set_industrial_estates.id', 'DESC')->paginate(25));
```

Can anybody help me to make this query faster and show me my issue?

Comment: If you update your resource query to `$this->customers->with('customeruser')->get(),` does this work?, basically without extention of the customer query

Comment: This runs into an error: Collection::with does not exist @Ashler2

Answer (score 1):

Even badly optimized queries with a pagination of 25, should be able to be executed fairly quick. If this is running locally it can be affected by hardware.

There is some misunderstandings in the relationship loading. If you execute queries with the relationship method and `get()` like `$this->customers()->with('customeruser')->get()` it will always execute a query for each time it is called, if you instead include all your data using `with()` and only accessing relationship like so `$this->customers`, it can fetch the same data with only 3 queries where before it would be 1 initial, 25 customer queries and a customeruser query.

To change you code. First eager load all your data using with, this will make laravel execute a relationship customer fetches on all your SetIndustrialEstate as a single query. Meanwhile also doing dot notation, to similar fetch the customeruser.

```
SetIndustrialEstate::orderBy('set_industrial_estates.id', 'DESC')
    ->with('customers.customeruser')
    ->paginate(25)
```

Change your resource to actually using the relationship instead of executing a new query.

```
'customers' => $this->customers,
```

As stated firstly with your amount of data even badly optimized queries should run fast, thou, ensuring there are indexes between your relationships will increase `SQL` performance. You can read how to do it in `Laravel` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). While an example could look like this, assuming you are using `MySQL` which automatically creates indexes on foreign keys.

```
Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('set_industrial_estate_id');
 
    $table->foreign('set_industrial_estate_id')->references('id')->on('set_industrial_estates');
});
```